# reading a formula from a spreadsheet with openxml

Tags: c#, excel, openxml, openxml-sdk

I'm reading a spreadsheet in C# using the Openxml library, and I'm parsing the values of the **Cell** object using **InnerText** propierty, that returns a **String** or **null**.

When in the **Cell** is present a formula, I get the literal text present in the spreadsheet, like that:

=Sheet1!A1Content

that is composed by: former formula ( Sheet1!A1 ) + string of the result ( Content )
and this happens also with basics like: =2+24

how do i get only the result of the formula?

Comment: have you tried a Google Search `C# Reading a Formula from a spreadsheet with OpenXml.?` http://openxmldeveloper.org/blog/b/openxmldeveloper/archive/2012/11/04/formula-processing-in-spreadsheetml.aspx

Comment: I did search but I didn't found that link. I'll start from there.

Comment: @MethodMan I read the page but I didn't found anything useful. I understood the structure of the formula but there isn't nothing about the reading of it, as I understood it

Answer (score 1):

From http://officeopenxml.com/ documentation:

> For a formula, the formula itself is stored within an **f** element as a child element of **c**. 
>       Following the formula is the actual calculated value within a  element.

There is also an example, this open xml for a single cell:

```
<c r="B9" s="3" t="str">
  <f>SUM(B2:B8)</f>
  <v>2105</v>
</c>
```

So in a `Cell` element, there is a child for the `Formula` and a child element for the `CellValue`. The `InnerText` property of the cell is the concatenated value of those two in your case.
If you already have the cell you need you can do the following:

```
static string GetValue(Cell cell)
{
   //The ? operator to make sure the 'CellValue' element exists, otherwise return null
   return cell.GetFirstChild<CellValue>()?.Text;
}
```

Comment: Hi Alexander, maybe you mean a Cell element?